# How to set specific indexes with values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply values to specific indexes in a large dataframe. They are two different labels created by a Classifier in sklearn. My attempt at doing so is...

```
for l in index_list:
    for i in high_low_results:
        df.set_value(l, ['estimate'], i)
```

According to the pandas documentation,  set_value is constructed like so. ( it seems to be exactly what im looking for.

Do i need to factorize the values first(aka turn them into integers?) As of now the "value" i, is either "high" or "low". Is there another way I can set values to specific indexes of a dataframe? thanks.

Parameters:

index : row label

col : column label

value : scalar value

takeable : interpret the index/col as indexers, default False

Returns:

frame : DataFrame

If label pair is contained, will be reference to calling DataFrame, otherwise a new object

Comment: `df.loc[index_list, 'estimate'] = high_low_results`?

Comment: man that was fast. U are a stackoverflow ninja. It worked! never knew about the second argument in .loc  thanks! ill upvote

Comment: I like turtles, so I respond

Comment: In the spirit of Stackoverflow, i must correct your comment. This is a tortoise. Seriously though, I appreciate the response and not just making fun of my terrible  formatting. I'm a bottle of wine deep and definitely didn't have proper spacing but instead of judgement you answered the question with no nonsense. Stackoverflow needs more like you sir.

Comment: No worries, I'm a couple of beers in myself. Enjoy ;-)